# Rails strange error => IndexError: string not matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I've got a very strange message error. I think it's not coming from Ruby but from the unix system.

So, I have the following test file:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper' 

class CatTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def test_truth
    assert true
   end
end
```

So, nothing coming from YAML files in the Fixtures directory.

When I run the test above with the command:

```
$ ruby ./test/unit/cat_test.rb
```

I get the very strange result:

```
Loaded suite ./test/unit/cat_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.011252 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_truth(CatTest):
IndexError: string not matched


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

I can't find the meaning of the error

```
IndexError: string not matched
```

But the most strange is that yesterday, It worked!

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards

(I'm working under Ubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 59):

This happens, for example, when you try to access a string variable as a Hash by mistake.

```
s = "a string"
s["position"] = "an other string"

IndexError: string not matched
    from (irb):5:in `[]='
    from (irb):5
```

[Additional Information](https://svn.cargo.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-2341)

Comment: In my case I was trying to access serialized json (a string) which I thought was JSON object

Answer (score 0):

As Simone points out the error is caused when you think you have a hash but really it a string. Its a genuine Ruby exception. I've had the exception due to a typo in my code. In your case I'm not sure of the cause but it could be something to do with a combination of Ruby / Rails versions.

You could try up/down grading Ruby or Rails to see if that fixes it.

For multiple Ruby versions I would highly recommended "RVM":http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/