# IndexError: string not matched using inject

Tags: ruby

This is what I want:

```
{ "[first_name]" => "first_name", "[last_name]" => "last_name" }
```

This is what I tried:

```
columns
# => ["first_name","last_name"]
columns.inject({}) do |acc, column|
  acc["[#{column}]"] = column
end
# => IndexError: string not matched
```

It seems to think acc is a string not a hash, as suggested here:

[Rails strange error => IndexError: string not matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072283/rails-strange-error-indexerror-string-not-matched)

But for sure acc is a hash. What is the problem here?

Comment: This is because `hash[key] = value` returns the value. For inject/reduce to work, the block has to return the accumulator (the hash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `merge!` to aggregate the result:

```
columns.inject({}) { |r, e| r.merge!({"[#{e}]" => e}) }
# => {"[first_name]"=>"first_name", "[last_name]"=>"last_name"}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `inject` with a Hash, make sure to return the modified hash at the end of the block:

```
columns.inject({}) do |acc, column|
  acc["[#{column}]"] = column
  acc
end

# => {"[first_name]"=>"first_name", "[last_name]"=>"last_name"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = columns.inject({}) do |acc, column|
  acc["[#{column}]"] = column
  acc
end
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to this answer. Otherwise, Dan would have to reason about what it does, even though that's reasonably simple here.