# Trouble passing data from view to controller/model in Ruby/Sinatra shopping cart

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm working on a shopping cart in Ruby Sinatra (TDD'd with Rspec and Capybara) and don't understand how to make the "Buy" button add an item to the cart.

Looking for some help understanding my problem and advice on refactoring, as I'm sure at this stage I'm making lots of dreadful mistakes.

What I think are the relevant parts:

View:

```
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <h3><div class="productName">
      <%= product["name"] %>
    </div></h3>

    <% if product["stock"] > 0 %>
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="item" class="buyButton">Buy</button>
      </form>
    <% else %>
      <button value="Sold out" class="soldOutButton" disabled>Sold out</button>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class RubyShop
  shop = Shop.new

  before do
    @products ||= shop.products
    @cart ||= shop.cart
  end

  get "/" do
    session[:item] = params["item"]
    @cart.add(session[:item])
    erb :products
  end

  post "/" do
    session[:item] = params["item"]
    @cart.add(session[:item])
    erb :products
  end
end
```

Models:

```
# shop.rb

require "json"
require_relative "cart"

class Shop
  attr_reader :products, :cart

  def initialize options = { products: "products.json" }
    file = File.read options[:products]
    @products = JSON.parse file
    @cart = Cart.new
  end
end

class Cart
  attr_reader :products

  def initialize
    @products = []
  end

  def add item
    return nil unless item
    add_quantity_value_to_hash item
    cart_contains_item?(item) ? increment_quantity(item) : add_product(item)
  end

  def add_quantity_value_to_hash item
    item["quantity"] ||= 1
  end

  def cart_contains_item? item
    @products.include? item
  end

  def increment_quantity item
    @products.find do |product|
      product["quantity"] += 1 if product["name"] == item["name"]
    end
  end

  def add_product item
    @products << item
  end

  def total
    @products.inject(0) do |sum, product|
      sum + (product["price"] * product["quantity"])
    end
  end
end
```

Sample JSON fixture:

```
[ { "name": "Black trainers",
    "category": "Footwear",
    "image": "http://www.img.com/1.jpg",
    "price": 100.00,
    "stock": 99 } ]
```

When click on "Buy" I get this error:

```
IndexError at /
string not matched
file: cart.rb location: []= line: 15
```

And my Rspec tests give me this error:

```
IndexError:
       string not matched
```

I've searched for the error on the web but not found a solution.

Comment: That error looks like it's coming from cart.rb line 15. What's there? Are you calling a hash method on a string?

Comment: I think I am calling a hash method on a string, I'm trying to make the Buy button send a hash from the JSON.  The cart.rb:15 is `item["quantity"] ||= 1`.  Can I not do that?

Comment: If item is a hash that will work, but you might want to make sure you don't have a typo and that item is really a hash at that scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072283/rails-strange-error-indexerror-string-not-matched

Comment: From the JSON fixture it looks like you are trying to send by POST a hash in an array, and that's probably not going to work as you expect it to, I suggest that you use a `p params` in your `post "/"` route to see exactly what is the structure received by Sinatra.

Comment: Thanks for the `p params` advice, I totally forgot I could do that.  The params I get are `{"item"=>"{"}` and have played around with some other things but I think I'm reaching a dead end with doing it this way.  I should really pass product IDs in the POST and retrieve the product by ID later right?