# IndexError (string not matched) when using send_data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My intention is to stream a JSON content as an attachment in Rails.
But it fails with `IndexError (string not matched)`.

I tried to transform `the_json` to binary, bytes...
I tried to set `the_json` as a hash and then use `to_json`...
I even tried to use a simple string like 'test'.
nothing worked. `send_data` always fail with same error.

This is the controller's action:

```
def get_jsonfile

  the_json = <<~JSON_CONTENT
    {
       "lorem": {
            "ipsum": []
        }
    }
  JSON_CONTENT

  send_data the_json,
            type: 'application/json',
            filename: 'file.json',
            disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update**

I figured out what I did wrong. And it didn't show up in this piece of code.

Before doing this update I was debugging the headers the edge servers in my stack where adding into the request. And in that controller, I created an action called `headers`

When `send_data` was trying to update the headers of the response, it was trying to write `headers["Content-Disposition"]` but `headers` was the result of the execution of my method (a string)... and then it failed exactly as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072348/486986

Thanks for the comments. Looking for the `Mime::Type` stuff I figured the best way to debug and understand my mistake here.

Comment: you have Mime::Type ?

Comment: Everything looks correct. Same code is working for me. Can you please post your error log here?